# Django, не грузится ннекоторая статика на хостинге

Tags: apache, django, nginx

Добрый день! У меня такой вопрос: есть сайт на Django, на локалхост все нормально работает, когда я переношу сайт на хостинг, и после переноса делаю collected static, то собирается вся статика и потом пости все нормально работет, но есть модуль блога Zinnia  и там не подключается статика редактора.

При этом есть ссылка на статику вот такая то не работает (они сейчас именно такие):

```
/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/skins/moono/editor_gecko.css?t=F7OI
```

а если вот такая то работает

```
/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/skins/moono/editor_gecko.css
```

т.е. в урле передается переменна ?t=F7OI

из-за которой почему-то не отдаётся файл статики.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое можно разрешить.

Заранее большое спасибо!

Веб-сервер на хостинге на статику Nginx, Скрипты Apache

Comment: может стоило бы показать конфиги?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем дело было в том, как `Django` обрабатывал статику. Ссылки вида `editor_gecko.css?t=F7OI` обрабатывались как запросы к скриптам. Нужно было указать `Django`, что из папки `static` - все это статика, и тогда заработало.

Comment: Допишите, как именно указать, что вся статика берется из папки `static`.